# Why is my tkinter window for hangman only appearing after the game has ended?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to python and I've been trying to code a simple hangman game using tkinter. However my tkinter window does not appear when I run the program, like it should. It appears only after the game has ended. i am really confused and cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import random


main = Tk()
main.title("Hangman game")
main.geometry("800x700+120+100")

#-----------------------------------------------------------1
pokusy = 5 
spatne_pis = "" 

slovo = ""
def vybrat_slovo(slovo):
    slovo = random.choice(open("slova_python.txt","r").read().split())
    return slovo

spravne_pis = "" 
neuhadle = ""
def ukazani(spatne_pis, spravne_pis, slovo):
    letters = ""
    for letter in spatne_pis:
        letters = letters + letter 
    pism_disp.set(" ".join(letters))
        
    print()
   
    neuhadle = "_"*len(slovo)
    for i in range(len(slovo)):
        if slovo[i] in spravne_pis:
            neuhadle = neuhadle[:i] +  slovo[i] + neuhadle[i+1:]
    slovo_disp.set(" ".join(neuhadle))
    return neuhadle

#----------------------------------------------------------------2



vrchni=Frame(main,width=800,height=50,bd=2,relief="raise")  
vrchni.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH)

hl_ramec=Frame(main,width=800,height=200,relief="raise") 
hl_ramec.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH)

klavesnice=LabelFrame(main,text='keys',width=800,height=300,bd=2,relief="raise") 
klavesnice.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH)

mezera=Frame(main,width=800,height=40,relief="raise") 
mezera.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH)

dolni=LabelFrame(main,text='comments',width=800,height=100,bd=2,relief="raise") 
dolni.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH)

hlaska = StringVar()
koment_lb = Label(dolni, textvariable = hlaska, font = ("Arial 22")).grid(padx=90, pady=20)


pomoc_rm=Frame(hl_ramec,width=400,height=300,relief='raise') 
pomoc_rm.pack(side=LEFT)

obrazek_ramec=LabelFrame(hl_ramec,text='Hangman - picture',width=400,height=300,bd=2,relief='raise') 
obrazek_ramec.pack(side=RIGHT)



status_rm=LabelFrame(pomoc_rm,text='status',width=350,height=80, relief='raise', padx = 10, pady=7) 
status_rm.pack(side=TOP)

zbyvajici = IntVar() 
pocet_lb = Label(status_rm, textvariable = zbyvajici, font=("Arial 22"))
pocet_lb.pack(side=RIGHT)
zbyvajici = pokusy - len(spatne_pis)

text_lb = Label(status_rm, text="Number of remaining guesses: ", font=("Arial 16"))
text_lb.pack(side=LEFT)


slovo_rm=LabelFrame(pomoc_rm,text='word',width=350,height=100,relief='raise') 
slovo_rm.pack(side=TOP)

slovo_disp = StringVar() 
slovo_lb = Label(slovo_rm, textvariable = slovo_disp, font = ("Arial 30")).grid(padx=30, pady=7)

zadane_rm=LabelFrame(pomoc_rm,text='wrong entered keys',width=350,height=80,relief='raise') 
zadane_rm.pack(side=TOP)

pism_disp = StringVar() 
pismena_lb = Label(zadane_rm, textvariable = pism_disp, font = ("Arial 16")).grid(padx=120, pady=15)

#vytvoření malé klávesnice pro uživatele
buttons = []  #seznam jednotlivých kláves
buttons = [
        'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p',
        'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',
        'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'
    ]

radek=3 
sloupec=0 


for button in buttons:
    command=lambda  x=button: select(x)
    if button!='Space':
        Button(klavesnice,text=button,width=5,font=("arial",14,"bold"),bg='powder blue',command=command,padx=3.5,pady=3.5,bd=5).grid(row=radek,column=sloupec)
    if button=='Space':
        Button(klavesnice,text=button,command=command).grid(row=5,column=sloupec)
    sloupec+=1
   
    if sloupec>9 and radek==3:
        sloupec=0
        radek+=1
    if sloupec>8 and radek==4:
        sloupec=0
        radek+=1

#---------------------------------------------------------3




uhadle_pis = ""
def hadani(uhadle_pis): 
    while True:
        hlaska = ("Try guessing a letter.")
        zadane = input()
        zadane = zadane.lower()
        if len(zadane) != 1:
            hlaska = ("Please enter only one letter")
        elif zadane in uhadle_pis:
            hlaska = ("You have already guessed that letter, try guessing again. :)")
        elif zadane not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            hlaska = ("Please enter a letter of the english alphabet. Entering other characters will not work.")
        else:
            return zadane
def hrat_znovu():
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


szn = ""
konec_hry = False
slovo = vybrat_slovo(slovo)
while True:
    ukazani(spatne_pis,spravne_pis,slovo)

    zadane = hadani(spatne_pis + spravne_pis)
    if zadane in slovo:
        spravne_pis = spravne_pis + zadane
        uhadnuto = True
        for i in range(len(slovo)):
            if slovo[i] not in spravne_pis:
                uhadnuto = False
                break
            if uhadnuto:
                konec_hry = True
                hlaska = ("Great job! You have succesfully guessed the word! The word was: ",slovo)
    else:
        spatne_pis = spatne_pis + zadane
        if len(spatne_pis) == pokusy:
            konec_hry = True
            hlaska = ("Sorry, you have been hanged. :(( The word was: ", slovo, ". Try playing again!")
           
    if konec_hry:
        if hrat_znovu():
            spatne_pis = ""
            spravne_pis = ""
            konec_hry = False
            slovo = vybrat_slovo(slovo)
        else:
            break
main.mainloop()
```

The code between the first #--- and second is maybe not important, but i want to include it to be sure. As i said, the tkinter only opens itself if the game has ended and the player does not want to play again. I will be very grateful for any answers :).

Comment: main.mainloop() is the last line of your program.  That's what displays the GUI.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks, I did not know that :). That said, should that line be at the beginning of the program?

Answer (score 0):

```
def gameloop():
    szn = ""
    konec_hry = False
    slovo = vybrat_slovo(slovo)
    while True:
        ukazani(spatne_pis, spravne_pis, slovo)

        zadane = hadani(spatne_pis + spravne_pis)
        if zadane in slovo:
            spravne_pis = spravne_pis + zadane
            uhadnuto = True
            for i in range(len(slovo)):
                if slovo[i] not in spravne_pis:
                    uhadnuto = False
                    break
                if uhadnuto:
                    konec_hry = True
                    hlaska = (
                    "Great job! You have succesfully guessed the word! The word was: ",
                    slovo)
        else:
            spatne_pis = spatne_pis + zadane
            if len(spatne_pis) == pokusy:
                konec_hry = True
                hlaska = ("Sorry, you have been hanged. :(( The word was: ", slovo,
                          ". Try playing again!")

        if konec_hry:
            if hrat_znovu():
                spatne_pis = ""
                spravne_pis = ""
                konec_hry = False
                slovo = vybrat_slovo(slovo)
            else:
                break
main.after(1000,gameloop)
main.mainloop()
```